# How do I redirect multiple domains to a single domain in lighttpd

Tags: web-server, lighttpd, redirection, redirect

If I have the following domains in lighttpd:
domain1.com
domain1.co.uk
domain2.com
domain2.co.uk

How do i redirect all these to to 'domain.com'?

ie:
domain1.co.uk/some-path/ redirects to domain.com/some-path/
and
domain2.com/some-other-path/ redirects to domain.com/some-other-path/

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "firsthost.example.com|secondhost.example.com|otherhost.example.net" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://realdomain.example.org/$1" )
}
```

should work - as covered in the man page ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [mod_redirect](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRedirect) as mentioned in the lighttpd docs. There are a number of examples that you can adapt.

Comment: I have and couldn't see a clear way todo this.

Comment: All you'd need to do is modify the first example slightly.